# Please help me to fix the array case of below

Tags: php

I have the code of below, and I want to asking about how to make the source to be insert on database in other table base on data earlier?

I get data from database and make it display on checkbox, but when I checklist the checkbox and press the button Tambah, the data is insert on the table but with wrong data, just 0 and array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>kumpulan data command</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Evaluation</h1>
 <h2>Data command</h2>
 <?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","FWS_online");
echo $db->connect_errno?'Koneksi gagal :'.$db->connect_error:'';
$query = ("SELECT * FROM printer_function_commands")  or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$pilihan = '';
$data = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['commands']))
{
    if (count($_POST['commands']) > 0)
    {
        $pilihan = serialize($_POST['commands']);
        echo "<p>Data berhasil disimpan ke database berupa ".$pilihan."</p>";
    }
}
if ($pilihan <> '')
{
    $data = unserialize($pilihan);
}
?>

 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Commands</th>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  include "database.php";
  $data1 = mysql_query("select * from result_commands");
  $no = 1;
  while($d = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['no_commands']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['commands']; ?></td>  
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
 </table>
 <br/>
 <h2>Input Banyak Data</h2>
 
<form method="post" action="tambah.php">  
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Commands</th>
    <th>Pilih</th>
   </tr>
   <?php 
   include "database.php";
   $data = mysql_query("select * from printer_function_commands");
   $no = 1;
   while($d = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
   ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['no_commands']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['commands']; ?></td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="pilih[]" value="<?php echo $d['id_commands']; ?>"></td> 
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Tambah">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

below code for add to database.

```html
<?php 
include 'database.php';
$id_commands = $_POST['pilih'];
$no_commands = $_POST['pilih'];
$jumlah_dipilih = count($no_commands);

for($x=0;$x<$jumlah_dipilih;$x++){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO result_commands VALUES(NULL,'$id_commands', '$no_commands')") or die(mysql_error());
}

header("location:index.php");
?>
```

and below I attached the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVZsh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- you are inserting array instead of value.

2- no_commands value also add in input hidden field to get the value after submit the form.

```
  $no_commands = $_POST['no_commands'];  //In table add this value in input hidden field to get the value after submit

    $id_commands = $_POST['pilih'];

    $jumlah_dipilih = count($id_commands); 
    /*Before iterate the array value check what data you are getting for 
      id_commands using print_r 
      like,  echo "<pre>"; print_r($id_commands); echo "</pre>"; 
     */
    for($x=0;$x<$jumlah_dipilih;$x++){ 
        $id_commands_val = $id_commands[$x]; //insert the id_commands value instead of array
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO result_commands VALUES(NULL,'$id_commands_val', '$no_commands')");
    }
```

---

***Update your code based on comments maybe it will help.***

```
<form method="post" action="tambah.php">    
    <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Commands</th>
                <th>Pilih</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $data = mysql_query("select * from printer_function_commands");
            $no = 1;
            while($d = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

            ?>
            <!-- no_commands value in hidden field -->
            <input type="hidden" name="pilih[<?php echo $no;?>][no_commands]" value="<?php echo $d['no_commands']; ?>">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $d['no_commands']; ?></td>   
                <td><?php echo $d['commands']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="pilih[<?php echo $no;?>][id]" value="<?php echo $d['id_commands']; ?>"></td>   
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $no++;
            } ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Tambah">
    </form>
```

tambah.php

```
<?php 
include 'database.php';
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $id_commands = $_POST['pilih'];

    /*echo "<pre>";
    print_r($id_commands);*/

    $id_commands_length = count($id_commands);
    for($i=1; $i<=$id_commands_length; $i++){

        if(isset($id_commands[$i]['id']) && $id_commands[$i]['id'] != ''){
            echo $id_commands_val = $id_commands[$i]['id'];
            echo $id_no_val = $id_commands[$i]['no_commands'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO result_commands VALUES(NULL,'$id_commands_val', '$id_no_val')") or die(mysql_error());
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: But I can add the data to other table with same database, but the data I selected is not same with data on previous table

Comment: Hi I have try with your code, but the data still added without data, the data could be blank.

Comment: I already try it with your update ans. But the result could not added the data on the table, and there is not  the responded. may be you have the email for make me can send the all script, and you can help me to fix this case. ^^

Comment: add code instead of image for display table in question will see. After adding the code remove the image.

Comment: Mysql_* functions do not exist in PHP anymore!

Comment: @ Dharman, 'the data is insert on the table but with wrong data, just 0 and array' - In question check

Comment: @ShivendraSingh I already update the post, you can see the script I created, how should I do to fix this case?

Comment: After submit the form just check what data are getting for $_POST['pilih']. and in table also add 'no_commands' value in hidden field to get this value after submit.

Comment: would you want to make the example because i'm still newbe ^^

Comment: An example to troubleshoot: `echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";`

Comment: @showdev when I try it with troubleshoot the result is Array
(
    [pilih] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [insert] => Tambah
)

Comment: Then within the `for` loop shown by Shivendra, when `$x` is zero, `$id_commands[$x]` should be "12" and that value should be inserted into your database. Try `echo $id_commands[$x];` and compare it to what's inserted.

Comment: @showdev there is no return data, what I should to do?

Comment: Try to find the point of failure. For example: What's the value of `$x`? What's the value of `$id_commands[0]`? Etc.

Comment: @showdev when I make view page source on the browser the value is right, the result => <td><input type="checkbox" name="pilih[]" value="12"></td>

Comment: @rotama pandi, I update the code for form and save the form data. Check.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh thank you very much, now the script can running as well

Comment: @rotama pandi, glad to help you. if it's working as you expected. Please mark this ans :)

Comment: Hi @ShivendraSingh Ok noted, I just click the symbol of checklist, right?

Comment: Yes...than you.